Driving 24 V DC DIN bistable (impulse) relay by Arduino
When I was doing reconstruction of electrical network in my apartment, I did it with possible future home automation in mind. Because of that, all my lights are driven by DIN impulse (bistable) relays from EATON. They are driven by 24 V DC from DIN switching power supply.
I started with development of a board with Arduino Nano that would act as a “smart switch” and will be sending the same 24 V DC impulses to the relays as when I hit a real switch on the wall.
My question is, what should I use as a switching component? I totally ditched use of a normal relay as I think that's not needed for 24 V DC and around 7 W of power that the DIN relay needs to flip the state. I was looking into SSR relays, but I think that because it is DC, I can go just with normal MOSFET? Is that feasible?
I was thinking about something like IRLML6344 as it is logic gate MOSFET and 30 V / 5 A seems enough.

Not sure if I can drive it directly from GPIO or I need e.g. resistor in front of the MOSFET?
Also, my concern is the possible inductance kickback from the relay. Is that a thing in this type of DIN relays?
One more concern is about shared ground reference. Is it OK for the Arduino board to share ground with the relay's power supply? Even if they will be two different DIN rail power supplies?


Do you have a datasheet link or part number for the relays you're using?  Also, what is a typical distance between the CPU and the relays.

Please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you are proposing. The devil's in the details, but without them it sounds like all you need is a few MOSFETs between your MCU and the relays, besides the normal pull-down and gate resistors.


Yes, the IRLML6344 appears to be logic level and can be directly driven by GPIO in low-side configurations. A small resistor (22 Ohm) to limit capacitive load on the GPIO is recommended. And ~47k pull-down to prevent spurious turn on when the chip is reset.

The inductive kickback is a valid concern. Best case this is resolved inside the relay, or with an addon. Regardless, a flyback diode must be places.

Sharing the ground does not have to a problem when the power supplies are sufficiently filtered and the beck-emf is correctly handled.


You can skip a lot of these concerns by using Smart High Side Switches, these are all-in high-side load switches that are suitable for inductive loads, will dampen inductive kickback and have short circuit (thermal) protection. Optionally with feedback. Eg: BTS4142N.
For your purpose they may not need any additional components at all.
For more robust implementations an external flyback and TVS diode would be recommended.

Thanks for answer. I am not sure if I will go with the Smart Hide Side Switch as it is kinda pricey at around $2 per one (I would need around 20 of them for all lights). I will go with the IRLML6344 or similar + flyback diode. Should I go with Schottky (e.g. SS14) or some TVS diode (not sure which one to pick there)?

@Baterka I would recommend against using a TVS diode as flyback. Though still diodes, its not what they are meant for and if you accidentally have bi-directional ones it won't work.

So just some 30V Schottky would be good enough?

@Baterka oh yes, rule of thumb is the average coil current and twice the voltage but as diode.
